# will stopService() stop a foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service

Will `stopService()` stop a service running as a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)?
It appears to, but also "feels" like it trumps the importance of foreground services.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirmed: Yes - running `stopService()` from an `Activity` outside of the service will stop the service -- even if the service is a foreground running service.

Answer (score 1):

It stops the service outright. It doesn't trump any importance, if your code is sending an Intent to stop the service, it would make perfect sense to obey said Intent.